# Send outlook email with JS?

Tags: javascript, performance, outlook

I want to send a email automatically with JS.

I use the next code to open a window with outlook with a mail with the information that I want.
Now I want to send the mail with JS. I need to "click" the send button automatically of the Outlook interface. Any ideas? Maybe with an Ajax /JQuery?

If anyone knows other process to send emails automatically with JS its usefull for me too.

```
function main(){

    location.href = "mailto:"+'someone@something.com'
            +'?cc='+" "
            +'&subject='+'something'
            +'&body='+"Hi, im an automatic mail";
}
```

Comment: Well you will not have controll over outlook via JS but you could send an ajax/post request to a server which can send out a mail if properly configured

Comment: well what you have is what you have to work with JavaScript in the browser with mail. Whatever is configured as the default mail client opens up.

Comment: I think the best solution its to open the Outlook (or other Email server) and put automatically your information in mailto, cc, subject or body, and wait for the user to press the send button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To details

Please note, JS is client side and runs inside browser, you do not have access to any application or file system outside browser or to browser itself..

Further,
If you need to send automated emails, you will need server side email engine configured and will need to make ajax / jQuery call to engine with recipient details..

Comment: Yes, I run the JS scripts in a Page located in a SharePoint Server, so I can run AJAX, JQuery task.

Comment: @MiwellJoestar great, but you will need email engine (SMTP) server configures at SharePoint and call from your JS